# Intent not switching to desired class @ java android

Tags: java, android

I've an Java Android application, which was working fine, but after 1 month, it stopped working at 1 flow.

When userA is paying for userB, and when payment is done, then userA should be redirected to new class (using intent)

But right now, it wont happening.

Here is a code

```
public void sendPayment(String type) {
    ProjectUtils.showProgressDialog(mContext, true, getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait));
    new HttpsRequest(Consts.MAKE_PAYMENT_API, getParms(type), mContext).stringPost(TAG, new Helper() {
        @Override
        public void backResponse(boolean flag, String msg, JSONObject response) {
            ProjectUtils.pauseProgressDialog();
            if (flag) {
                ProjectUtils.showToast(mContext, msg);
                Intent in = new Intent(mContext, WriteReview.class);
                in.putExtra(Consts.HISTORY_DTO, historyDTO);
                startActivity(in);
                finish();
            } else {
                ProjectUtils.showToast(mContext, msg);

            }
        }
    });
}
```

After debugging, I can see, that **backResponse** is fully ignored and user is always stayed in same view.

In previous version versions it was working fine.

I'm not a developer, so hard to understand why it was happening like this.

Can it be failure of API (i was changing something there)
UPD:

Logcat results, after I did payment.

```
sendPaymentConfirm: {payment_type=1, final_amount=0.02, discount_amount=0, invoice_id=Z2EUGKN5B32H, payment_status=1, user_id=614, coupon_code=}

PaymentProActivity:  error body --->null error msg --->org.json.JSONException: Value <div of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

But payment was success

Thank you

Comment: If something is working - then a change is made - then it is not working anymore, it´s most likely the change that caused the issue. So I suggest you post the relevant parts of the API that got changed. By the way out of curiosity : How come you change API´s and are not a developer?

Comment: @GitPhilter, nothing were changed in scope of java this is 100%, maybe smnth on API side, but im not sure. I'm 20-30% developer, and 70-80% automation ;)

Comment: Ok, but nobody will be able to tell you why backRespond() "gets ignored" if we don´t see the part where this function is supposed to be called.

Comment: I guess, something wrong with JSON , i 've added response to question