# value Data of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject @ java android

Tags: java, android, json

Can you help, why I'm getting this error in logcat?
Recently it was OK since I moved to SDK 28, it is failing. But I'm not sure that this is an issue of SDK 28.
Payment is getting OK (user receives a payment, but Intent isn't working and in Logcat I got this error)

Can you suggest something? 
thank you

```
public void sendPayment(String type) {
            ProjectUtils.showProgressDialog(mContext, true, getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait));
            new HttpsRequest(Consts.MAKE_PAYMENT_API, getParms(type), mContext).stringPost(TAG, new Helper() {
                @Override
                public void backResponse(boolean flag, String msg, JSONObject response) {
                    ProjectUtils.pauseProgressDialog();
                    if (flag) {
                        ProjectUtils.showToast(mContext, msg);
                        Intent in = new Intent(mContext, WriteReview.class);
                        in.putExtra(Consts.HISTORY_DTO, historyDTO);
                        startActivity(in);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        ProjectUtils.showToast(mContext, msg);

                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

```
    public Map<String, String> getParms(String type) {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(Consts.INVOICE_ID, historyDTO.getInvoice_id());
            params.put(Consts.USER_ID, userDTO.getUser_id());
            params.put(Consts.COUPON_CODE, coupon_code);
            params.put(Consts.FINAL_AMOUNT, final_amount);
            params.put(Consts.PAYMENT_STATUS, "1");
            params.put(Consts.PAYMENT_TYPE, type);
            params.put(Consts.DISCOUNT_AMOUNT, discount_amount);

            Log.e("sendPaymentConfirm", params.toString());
            return params;
        }
```

UPD:
errors

```
sendPaymentConfirm: {payment_type=1, final_amount=150, discount_amount=0, invoice_id=RCVG2QNWBHCP, payment_status=1, user_id=614, coupon_code=}

PaymentProActivity:  error body --->null error msg --->org.json.JSONException: Value <div of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intent not switching to desired class @ java android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58145101/intent-not-switching-to-desired-class-java-android)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error you are getting in logcat (including stacktrace).

Comment: @JohannesKuhn, added

Comment: @EasyJob Meistars You just posted almost the same question regarding the same function a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved, by downgrade from PHP 7.2, to PHP 7.1